# Issue with xml attributes count in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion-8

My code is

```
<cfxml variable="str">
  <root>
<T id="1" name="jaggu"></T>
<T id="2" name="jaggu2"></T>
</root>
</cfxml>

<cfset MyXMLDoc = xmlParse(str)>
<cfset packages = xmlSearch(MyXMLDoc, '/root/T')>


    <cfoutput>
        #structcount(packages[1])#
    </cfoutput>
```

I am getting 0 but there are 2 atttributes in tag T

Is there any way to get count of xmlattributes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're asking for the wrong information. You're asking for the number of structs in the first match, which is in fact 0. If you want the number of attributes on the T tag, you need to get the count of the `xmlAttributes` node, like so:

```
#structcount(packages[1].xmlAttributes)#
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the response as the answer if it did indeed fix your issue.